# paperclip doesn't show my custom message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip, paperclip-validation

I have a Rails 4 app using Paperclip 4.3.2. I have the following specified in my model:

```
    validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/, :message => "some message"
```

When I try to load a wrong file I hoped to find the message "some message" but I get the message:

> Avatar translation missing: ca.activerecord.errors.models..attributes.avatar.spoofed_media_type

Any idea what's going wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

```
validates_attachment :avatar,
  content_type: { content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/, message: "Some Message" }
```

[Good ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19806340/1143732)

---

To give you some context as to the `Avatar translation missing` error - this is typically caused by a lack of [I18n](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html) translations...

```
# config/locales/[[lang]].yml
ca:
  activerecord:
    errors:
      models:
         attributes:
           spoofed_media_type: "Message"
```

[This](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issues/14) should give you some insight.

---

Finally, ["spoofed media type"](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/prevent-spoofing-with-paperclip) errors often mean you don't have the [`file`](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#file) (or equivalent) on your system. I can only speak from Windows experience; you need to set `file` up separately if you don't have [`DevKit`](http://rubyinstaller.org/add-ons/devkit/) installed.

Comment: Thanks Rich for your answer, but I'm trying to be DRY with locale's entries. My application has about 90 models that have attachment :avatar. With this solution I must create a locale entry for each one of them. I would like a single message to all application validates_attachment_content_type. So I'm trying to force the message on validates_attachment_content_type but paperclip always search the message error in locale key activerecord.errors.<model>.attributes.spoofed_media_type.

Comment: Why don't you just have a central "asset" model? We used the reference [here](http://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/2010/08/18/use-sti-and-polymorphic-model-for-multiple-uploads/) and have 1 `asset` model storing all our attachments: http://i.imgur.com/fVX850Y.png