# Display errors messages for associated model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, paperclip

This is my `Article` Model

```
class Article

has_many :pictures, autosave: true, dependent: :destroy

validates :title, presence: true
validates :text, presence: true
```

This is my `Picture` Model

```
class Picture
include Mongoid::Document
include Mongoid::Paperclip

belongs_to :article
has_mongoid_attached_file :pic,
    preserve_files: true,
    :url => "/public/pictures/:style/:basename.:extension",
    styles: { format: "400x400", thumb: "150x150>" }


validates_attachment :pic, content_type: { content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\z/ },
size: { in: 50.kilobytes..3.megabytes }
```

I want to display all errors messages in my view, but if picture is invalid i have many messages for one error. For example if content type is invalid i have:

1. "Pictures invalid" in `@article.errors.full_messages`(i don't need it)
2. "Pic invalid" in `@article.pictures.first.full_messages`(i don't need it)
3. "Pic_content_type invalid" in `@article.pictures.first.full_messages`(it's only one message i really need)

Any ideas? Thanks in advance and sorry for my English

Comment: how are you generating the form?

Comment: I use form_for helper.

Comment: How can i change @article.errors.full_message "Pictures invalid" to "Picture *picture_name* pic_content_type invalid"? Is it possible?

Comment: you can customize your validations here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html make sure to quote me in an answer to have more help

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question but a few things come to mind you might be able to investigate.

Paperclip comes with some [validation](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#validations) options and you may want to consider modifying them to produce your desired error messages as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10711504/cleaning-up-paperclip-error-messages).

It seems you may need to pick the proper error message(s) to display by traversing the array of error messages received.

```
@article.pictures.first.full_messages[index of message you want to display]
```

On another note, I saw that you use a reg exp pattern for your content type validation and the Paperclip docs warn against vulnerabilities if this is left open. They recommend something like the this:

```
validates_attachment :pic, 
 content_type: { content_type: ["image/jpeg", "image/gif", "image/png"] }
```

I hope that's at least little helpful.

Comment: For example: i try to create article and i enter invalid text(too short) and upload invalid fail(not image, pdf for example). I want to find good way to show two messages  something like this "Text is too short" and "File *file_name* has invalid type".

Comment: This post covers changing the messages that come with paperclip validations:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10711504/cleaning-up-paperclip-error-messages

If you follow their pattern and keep your current validation it would like this for content type:
`validates_attachment :pic, content_type: { content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\z/, :message => "File file_name has invalid type" },
size: { in: 50.kilobytes..3.megabytes }`

Then you can pass the error to your view from the controller by using [Rails Flash](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Flash.html).